# Android: video playback with alpha channel?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, video, alpha-transparency

In iOS I can to play videos with an alpha channel using http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator

How should I approach this on Android?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cal, you will likely need to just use a series of PNG images. H.264 does not support an alpha channel at all, so that is not going to work for you. A series of PNG images is going to be very large in your app and it will not load quickly, but it would at least provide a very poor alpha channel functionality. You might also be able to compile WebM for Andrioid, but I have no idea how hard that would actually be to get working and it will likely be rather slow since video decoding would be done in software.